# Why ImageDataGenerator mdoel.fit_generator showing error Function call stack: keras_scratch_graph?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, image-recognition

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
    samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
    featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
    samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
    zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
    rotation_range=10,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
    zoom_range = 0.1, # Randomly zoom image 
    width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
    height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
    horizontal_flip=False,  # randomly flip images
    vertical_flip=False)  # randomly flip images
```

datagen.fit(X_train)

---

```
history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train,Y_train,batch_size=batch_size,),
                         epochs=epochs,validation_data=(X_val,Y_val),
                         verbose=2,steps_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0] // batch_size,                             
                        callbacks= [learning_rate_reduction])
```

> InternalError:  Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(86, 3136), b.shape=(3136, 256), m=86, n=256, k=3136
>        [[node dense_1/MatMul (defined at c:\users\shahj\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_1528]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph

Answer (score 0):

[try this worked for me](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10-60693e46e781)

cuda version --> '10.0'  cudnn version --> '7.6.4'

tensorflow gpu version --> '2.0.0'  keras gpu version --> '2.2.4'